# How to merge two tables according to the relation in a third table?

Tags: mysql, relational-database, relational-algebra

Suppose there are 3 tables:

> student
>
> teacher
>
> advisor

Student has name and id columns, teacher also has name and id columns and advior has `s_id`(stands for student id) and `t_id` (stands for teacher id). 
s_id references to id in student table and t_id references to id in teacher table.
How can I merge the name of the student with name of his advisor?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create supervisor id in student table to merge the supervisor with his students and use join Statement

Answer (score 1):

You can use join to merge the tables.

Try this:

```
select b.name,c.name from advisor a
join student b on a.s_id = b.id
join teacher c on a.t_id = c.id
where a.s_id = 1
```

Note that a, b and c are aliases.